# Query Facebook for Name and Picture with ID

Tags: php, facebook, api, rest, curl

I am developing a script where I update the name and profile picture of users every other week or so (to stay updated with their information).

I need to figure out how to use Facebook's API to get the name and profile picture of a user using their facebook ID.

I'm using PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `/userid` call and filter for name and picture.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/the_user_id?fields=name,picture
```

Returns

```
{
   "name": "First LastingName",
   "id": "the_user_id",
   "picture": "The image.jpg"
}
```

If you are using the PHP SDK you can do

```
$user = $facebook->api('/the_user_id');
$name = $user['name'];
$picture = $user['picture'];
```

For more information on `user` see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/